# Warning: move_uploaded_file(../project/discussdesk.xlsx): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, phpexcel, import-from-excel

```
Reading data from excel sheet and insert into mysql server.
but displaying errors as :
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../project/discussdesk.xlsx): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\upload.php on line 17
```

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php97D7.tmp' to '../project/discussdesk.xlsx' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\upload.php on line 17

```
<?php

    $uploadedStatus = 0;

    if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
    if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    //if there was an error uploading the file
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
    if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
    $storagename = "discussdesk.xlsx";
    //$root = getcwd();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "../project/".$storagename);


    $uploadedStatus = 1;
    }
    } else {
    echo "No file selected <br />";
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Looks like a file permission problem to me. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that your /project/.$storagename has 777 permission. It seems like your destination folder does not have any permission. Another thing after looking into your code i cant understand what actually you are trying to do. Are you trying to save a file into a excel file?

Because $storagename = 'discussdesk.xlsx' {It is the destination}

and you are trying to store a whole file into this file??

Comment: when i try to change permission for $storagename it says as Acces denined permission cannot change.

I'm trying to read excel data and send it mysql table...

Comment: Your code is wrong, you are actually moving your uploaded file into a excel file, it is not possible. better to google for any API to read excel file. for reading an excel file why did you need upload?? are you want to read the last uploaded file??